# Java 環境変数 LANG=C だと 日本語ファイル名がうまく扱えない

Tags: java, 日本語

環境変数 `LANC=C` で 日本語ファイル名を扱いたいと思っています。

## 内容

しかし、以下の様な Java のプログラムで日本語ファイル名を読もうとすると
`LANG` の設定によってはうまくいきません。

```
import java.io.File;
class Test {
    static public void main(String args[]){
        File dir = new File("somedir");
        for (String f : dir.list())
            System.out.println(f);
    }
}
```

実行すると、こんな感じになります。

```
% echo $LANG
ja_JP.UTF-8
% java Test
い
う
あ

% LANG=C java Test
???
???
???
```

### 前提条件

日本語ファイル名のファイルは事前に以下の様に作りました。

```
% mkdir somedir
% touch somedir/あ
% touch somedir/い
% touch somedir/う
```

### Javaのプロパティ

関係ありそうだなと思ったので、 
`LANG` が `ja_JP.UTF-8` と `C` の場合の
`System.getProperties()` の差を調べると
以下の4点が違う様でした
- user.country
- user.language
- sun.jnu.encoding
- file.encoding

以下を `C` と `ja_JP.UTF-8` で実行してみて `diff` で調べました。

```
class Prop {
    static public void main(String args[]){
        java.util.Properties p = System.getProperties();
        for (Object k : p.keySet())
            System.out.println(k + ": " + p.get(k));
    }
}
```

それで以下の様に `LANG=C` にして、
上の4つを `ja_JP.UTF-8` のときと同じになる様に実行してみましたが
やはりうまく表示されません。

```
% LANG=C java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 \
              -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 \
              -Duser.country=JP \
              -Duser.language=ja \
              Test
```

でも、最初に `LANG=C java Test` で実行したときとは
違う文字が出ている様でした。
どちらにしろ読めないですが

## 出力まとめ

出力はまとめると以下の様になります

```
# うまく表示される
% java Test | hexdump -C
00000000  e3 81 84 0a e3 81 86 0a  e3 81 82 0a              |............|
0000000c

# うまく表示されない
% LANG=C java Test | hexdump -C
00000000  3f 3f 3f 0a 3f 3f 3f 0a  3f 3f 3f 0a              |???.???.???.|
0000000c

# うまく表示されない    
% LANG=C java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=JP -Duser.language=ja Test | hexdump -C
00000000  ef bf bd ef bf bd ef bf  bd 0a ef bf bd ef bf bd  |................|
00000010  ef bf bd 0a ef bf bd ef  bf bd ef bf bd 0a        |..............|
0000001e
```

## 環境

OS は Ubuntu です

```
% cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS \n \l
% uname -a
Linux ub 3.13.0-74-generic #118-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 17 22:52:10 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
% java -version
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)
```

なにかヒントが頂けるとうれしいです。
また、ここを調べた方がいいというポイントがあれば、教えて下さい。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `LANG` だけが `C` にセットされている、という状況であれば、`LC_CTYPE` を `UTF-8` に設定する方法もあるかと思います。`LC_CTYPE=ja_JP.UTF-8 LANG=C java Test`

Comment: ありがとうございます。

これで大丈夫でした。
https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libc/manual/html_node/Locale-Categories.html
あたりを読めばよさそうですね。

Comment: 提示された回答について調べた結果を共有していただけるのはありがたいのですが、それは質問の追加情報というより回答ですよね。どこまでが質問なのかわかりやすいように、ご自身で回答として投稿していただけないでしょうか？併せてこちらもご覧ください： http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/1736/8000

Comment: ルールが分かってなくてすみません。質問と追記した部分を分けてみました。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

各種プロパティを手動で設定したときに出力される `ef bf bd` は、Unicodeで表現できない文字を表す[「置換文字」](http://smdn.jp/programming/netfx/tips/encoding_fallback/)のUTF-8表現です。Javaは内部的に文字列をUTF-16で扱っているようなので、 `dir.list()` の時点で前述の置換文字に化けていて、それを `3f` で出すか `ef bf bd` で出すかが切り替わっているだけなのではないでしょうか。

調べてみると、`java.io.File` でのファイル名の扱いはロケール設定やOSによって変化するという話がちらほら見つかります。Macでは動いたというのはこのあたりの絡みかもしれません。

- [java read write unicode / UTF-8 filenames (not contents) - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14171565/2818869)
- [How can I open files containing accents in Java? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3072376/2818869)

どちらの質問にも `java.nio.Files` で解決したという情報が寄せられているので、ひょっとしたらこれで解決するかもしれません。（標準出力へ書き出す際のエンコーディングは別途考慮が必要だと思いますが）

Comment: ありがとうございます。出来ました。分かり易い様に、試した内容は本文に追記しました。実は Clojure でトラブっていて、現象を単純化する為にJavaまで降りて調べていたので、残念ながら NIO は使えないのですが、Javaも文字コードも詳しくないので勉強になって良かったです。表現できない文字の対応が組込まれているんですね。

Answer (score 3):

私はMac OS Xですが、

```
$ LANG=C java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 \
              -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 \
              -Duser.country=JP \
              -Duser.language=ja \
              Test
```

で日本語出ましたよ。

また、求めている事とは違うかも知れないですが、エンコードを指定して出力すれば、LANG=Cでも日本語で出力されます。

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintStream;
    class Test {
    static public void main(String args[]){
        File dir = new File("somedir");
        try {
            PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
            for (String f : dir.list())
                out.println(f);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            ;
        }
    }
}
```

結果

```
$ LANG=C java Test
あ
い
う
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。


mac だとまた違うんですね。
java の run anywhere 的な部分を求めるなら、環境変数とかファイルとかに依存しない方がいいのかもしれないですね。
といってもお手軽さも欲しいので悩ましいです。


あと、実はファイル名を出力したいというより、
そのファイルを開きたいというのがあるので、
PrintStream のやつでは要件を満せないんです。
せっかく教えてもらったのにすみません。。。

Answer (score 1):

`LANG`は**使用言語を表す**環境変数で、**文字コードにも影響します**。`LANG=C`の場合、使用される文字コードはASCIIです。ASCIIに日本語の文字は**定義せれていません**。ロケールを英語にしたいのであれば`LANG=C`ではなく、`LANG=en_US.UTF-8`を指定してみましょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。この方法でもうまくいきました。
あんまり考えた事なかったですが LANG は、
language, territory, codeset とかを指定できるんですね。
solaris の資料ですけど
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26924_01/html/E27144/glmbx.html
に書いてありました。

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html#tag_07_02
で、POSIX の LANG=C も見てみたのですが、ASCIIコードとかの話は出てないですね。普通はそうなってるんですかね?

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/ にある通り、POSIXロケール(Cロケール)では**ポータブル文字セット**と**制御文字セット**に定義されてる文字を扱うことができます。すなわち、それ以外の文字を扱えることは保証されてません。例えば https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch08.en.html でDebianはPOSIXロケール下ではASCIIを使用すると定めらています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。なるほど分かりました。portable character set とあったので「何だ portable って?」と思っていたんですが、よく見ると THE portable character set って書いてありますね。これが POSIX portable character set を指してるわけですね。僕は POSIX portable character set の存在を知らなかったんですけど、それでこれと制御文字を合わせると ASCII になるって事ですね、多分。

Answer (score 1):

## java.nio で対応する

java.nio でうまくらしいと、教え頂いたので試してみました。
結果としては、うまくいきました。

プログラムは以下です

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try(DirectoryStream<Path> dir = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("somedir"))){
            for(Path file : dir)
                System.out.println(file.getFileName());
        } catch(IOException | DirectoryIteratorException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

これを以下の様に実行すると大丈夫でした。

```
LANG=C java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 \
            -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 \
            Test
```

file.encoding, sun.jnu.encoding 両方指定しないとダメでした。

### この対応のいいところや特徴

この方法は Java で完結するので、
OSとかの依存をなくしたい場合はこっちの方法がいいと思います。

でも普通はなくしたいので、
maven とかで入れたりした依存ライブラリの中で
java.io を使っていて java.nio に変えられない
とかでなければ、こっちを使った方がいいのかなと思います。

Answer (score 1):

## 環境変数で対応する

環境変数で対応する方法を2つ教えて頂いたので、それに関して追記します。

### LANG と LC_CTYPE を設定する方法

```
LC_CTYPE=ja_JP.UTF-8 LANG=C java ....
```

などとやる。
他にも `LC_なんとか` という名前の環境変数があって、
それを設定する事で、`LC_TIME` なら地域毎の時間の表示方法とかを変えられるみたいです。

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26924_01/html/E27144/glmbx.html#glmbc

に他のものもいくつか載っています。

`LANG` も一緒に設定する事で、`LC_CTYPE` 以外は `C` に設定という風になるみたいです。
`LANG` < `LC_なんとか` という優先順位になっているからみたいです。

もうちょっと詳しく書くと
`LANG` < `LC_なんとか` < `LC_ALL`
という優先順位みたいです

### LANG だけ設定する方法

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 java ...
```

などとやる。
これで、英語で UTF-8 を使うという設定になるみたいです。
`LANG=C` だと、UTF-8 じゃなくて ASCII になるそうです。

LANG に設定できる値は、

```
locale -a
```

で調べられます(OSに追加すれば増えます)

書式は https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26924_01/html/E27144/glmbx.html によると

```
language[_territory][.codeset][@modifier]
```

になっているみたいです

なので、`ja_JP.UTF-8` なら
- language  => ja
- territory => JP
- codeset   => UTF-8
という事みたいです。

### この対応のいいところや特徴

プログラム本体の書換えがいらない

環境変数を使っているので OS に依存してそう。
もちろん、全OSを検証したわけじゃないですが、
Macだと大丈夫だったという報告も頂いたので、
少なからずそういう部分があるのかなと思います。

もしかすると、JVMの実装で違う結果になっている可能性もありますが。